# Laravel Eloquent tablename extraordinary plural form

Tags: laravel

I’d like to create an Eloquent table that‘s called criteria. The right singular form would be criterion. Does anybody know, if Laravel is smart enough to recognize this extraordinary singular and plural forms?

Comment: Yes, Laravel is smart enough for it `php artisan make:migration Criterion -m` creates a migration for table `criteria`

Comment: Thanks, that’s nice!